# Three 10mb fibre lines individually for three houses or a single 100mb line extended across three houses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, wifi-configuration

I have three houses close by together and would like to get wifi in each house. Currently, each house has 10mb fibre lines each.

I'd like to know if it would be possible to have a single 100mb fibre line connected to a router in one house that I can extend, using LAN cables and routers, to the other two houses. If this is possible, would this give a better connection (would be okay for gaming, streaming, etc.) to each house as opposed to the current set up of a 10mb line in each house?

Comment: How close is close?

Comment: @DanielB Roughly around 100 meters of cabling to one router and 200 meters to the other.

Comment: Each time you extend the network like the way you describe it would effectively cut your bandwidth in half.

Comment: What kind of fiber? Single mode? Multimode? What diameter? Do you control both ends of all three existing fiber runs, or do those three runs each go straight to an ISP? If you own these runs and they're the right variety of fiber, you might be able to replace your 10Mbps transceivers with, say, gigabit transceivers and still use the existing fiber.

Comment: @Spiff It's Single-mode, and the three runs go to an ISP.

Comment: @Ramhound so this should still work out better than 10mb lines in each house, correct?